# Unable to run "apt-get -f install"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run `sudo apt-get purge postgresql*`, but I get a dependency error and a suggestion to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, so I try to run it which gives me:

```
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic (3.13.0-63.104~precise1) over (3.13.0-63.103) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.104~precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/modules/3.13.0-63-generic/kernel/mm/hwpoison-inject.ko', which is also in package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic 3.13.0-63.103
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic_3.13.0-63.104~precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm on 14.04

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get autoremove` then trying `sudo apt-get -f install` and see if it changes anything

Comment: @NooBskie It seems to loop back around. Here's what I get: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-signed-image-3.13.0-63-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic (= 3.13.0-63.104~precise1) but 3.13.0-63.103 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
`

Comment: What about after running `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: `apt-get update` finishes without errors but `apt-get -f install` still gives the same errors

Answer (score 7):

It seems there is a problem with installer. This command should help:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After this, you should be able to install required dependencies

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't verify if this would work because I gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu. But thanks for the help anyway!